# Show current time with a given GMTOffset in Windows 8

Tags: datetime, windows-8, timezone

I have the GMTOffset in the format UTC/GMT +1.00 hour. I am creating a clock app in windows 8 and want to show the clocks current timing with this GMToffset. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a converter and format your DateTime:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("ddd, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz");
```

which will give you this string:

```
Wed, 27 March 2013 14:33:14 +01:00
```

The source for a converter can look like this:

```
public class DateTimeConverter : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (value is DateTime)
        {
            return ((DateTime)value).ToString("ddd, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"); 
        }
        return value
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Suppose DateTime.Now(in india) is 11.51 am so I want to show the time of US now. for that I have the GMT offset how do I convert the current indian time to US time after applying the GMT offset to it?

Comment: Check this link out for datetime conversion between timezones: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397769.aspx